# Open popup if the user visits n number of pages in a directory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of recipes in site, which are located in recipes directory, for example:

```text
./recipes/muffin
./recipes/cake
./recipes/bread
```

I already have some code which counts sessions. How can I trigger when user opens a page with the third recipe? I need to open popup in this action too.

```
// Open it once per session, after some time, show overlay & disable scroll in desktop & mobile devices
if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.newsletter_popup').show();
    }, 1000);
    sessionStorage.alreadyClicked = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every recipe page visited you can increment a counter:

```
sessionStorage.recipesViewed = (sessionStorage.recipesViewed || 0) + 1;
```

Then you can check that value to see if this is the third recipe viewed in this session:

```
if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked || sessionStorage.recipesViewed == 3) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.newsletter_popup').show();
  }, 1000);
  sessionStorage.alreadyClicked = 1;
}
```

If you need to count each recipe individually (so that refreshing the same page three times would not make the popup appear) you would need to make the logic a little more complex by storing the URL of the page along with the view counter and keeping a unique total.

Comment: Thanks for such fast answer! And session storage knows about url? So the 'recipesViewed' is watching /recipes/.. directory?

Comment: No, it's completely agnostic of the URL. You would need to manually put the first line of code in to the pages which run under that directory.

Comment: You can get the current url with `window.location.href`. You would need to split the string apart to get the folder. If you need help with that you should start a new question.